# ExpandableListFragment android

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-listfragment, expandablelistadapter

```
public class ProfileFragment extends ListFragment
{  
        /** An array of items to display in ArrayList */
        String profile_list[] = new String[]{
            "Personal Info",
            "Account Info"
        };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        /** Creating array adapter to set data in listview */
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, profile_list);

        /** Setting the array adapter to the listview */
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }    

    @Override
    public void onStart()
    {     
        super.onStart();
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int pos, long id)
    {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, pos, id);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item " + pos + " was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And here is my adapter

```
public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    final int PAGE_COUNT = 2;

    /** Constructor of the class */
    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
    {
        super(fm);
    }

    /** This method will be invoked when a page is requested to create */
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0)
    {
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        switch(arg0)
        {
            /** Home tab is selected */
            case 0:
                HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment(); 

                data.putInt("current_page", arg0+1);
                homeFragment.setArguments(data);
                return homeFragment;

            /** Profile tab is selected */
            case 1:
                ProfileFragment profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();

                data.putInt("current_page", arg0+1);
                profileFragment.setArguments(data);
                return profileFragment; 
        }

        return null;
    }

    /** Returns the number of pages */
    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {       
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }
}
```

There are two items on the second tab page, i.e. Personal Info and Account Info. I want to add their children like when user click on Personal Info list will expand and show their sub items and hide when user click again.

please tell me the solution with minimum changes in existing code.

thanks in Advanced

Comment: Create a fragment that holds a expandable listview here take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22067471/expandablelistview-in-fragment-expandable-list-not-display